# Windows 10 slows down after Edge or Git usage

Tags: windows-10, performance

I have a fresh Windows 10 installation, which is getting slow ~ 10 to 30s after logging in the first time. The system is not lagging otherwise. I'm a kind of clueless.

My setup:

- Dell OptiPlex 7040
- 32 GB RAM
- i7-6700@3,4 GHz
- ADATA SS DP910 1 TB
- Windows 10 Pro

My test measure:

1. hit Ctrl+Shift+Esc and wait for the task manager
2. type cmd in the search bar and right-click run as admin

Within the first seconds after logging in, this are instant operations, including UAC fading. Later it needs 10 or more seconds.

What I did/tried:

- reset windows
- deinstall all DELL stuff
- install and deinstall the company firewall solution
- disable Windows defender
- benchmark the SSD with reasonable good results
- remove all the stuff from autostart
- disabled page files
- log out and in will not give me another fast period
- disable bitlocker
- disable non-ms-services
- switch to "full-power" energy mode
  Any further ideas what the root cause might be or what I can do to investigate this?

My next steps/ideas:

- disable random services and hope the best
- or the SSD?

Edit 1:

Restart, login and only open the task manager worked for over 3 minutes without getting slower, then I opened the explorer and the Taskmanager was still fast. **Opening Edge with the previous page and close it right away let to the slow Taskmanger opening.** 
Doing the same with FF works fine. Copying stuff has also no impact. 
**A git fetch (with credential manager) seems to slow it down again.**

Edit 2:
Reset it again. Everything is fine. Only join our company domain -> slow. According the event log it might be DNS related.

Comment: So did you manage to solve that problem? 10 seconds after login looks like anti-virus.

Comment: We removed all our windows 10 system from the domain and everything is fine. Our last guess was some interaction between Samba and the ActiveDirectory.